# Calling a port after view is updated in Elm

Tags: elm, elm-port

Is there a straightforward way to have a `Cmd` execute after the view is updated? In particular, I’m trying to reposition the cursor in a `textarea` upon specific keys (like the enter key) being pressed. In my `update` function I have:

```
case keyboardEvent.key of
    "Enter" ->
        ( modelAfterEnterPressed model keyboardEvent.selectionStart, setCursor model.cursor )
    "Tab" ->
        ....
```

My `setCursor` port is called and the corresponding JavaScript code calls the `textarea`‘s `setSelectionRange` function properly. And *then* Elm calls my `view` function which updates the `textarea`‘s content. Unfortunately, that wipes out my cursor position.

I need for the `textarea`‘s content to be updated *before* calling `textarea.setSelectionRange()` in my JavaScript port. Any way to do this without resorting to `setTimeout` which might not always work and can cause flashes within the timeout?

Answer (score 6):

The standard way to do this is to trigger a command that returns in the next tick - e.g. Date.now - and then trigger the port command from that message. That guarantees that the view function will have run and your text area is present.

An alternative, which seems to work as well in my experience, is to replace a `setTimeout` (with an arbitrary interval) with a requestAnimationFrame:

```
elm.ports.selectText.subscribe( () => {
  requestAnimationFrame( () => {
    var textarea = document.querySelector(...);
    textarea.setSelectionRange();
  });
});
```

This will trigger after the `view` has been rendered too.

Comment: Elm actually has a built-in subscription function for `requestAnimationFrame()`: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/animation-frame/latest/AnimationFrame. My concern was that typed keys could be registered/processed between the first `KeyboardEvent` and the next animation frame. That would throw everything off.